# Making an Add to Favorites button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need help using cookies to save information when the user clicks the *Add to favorites* button.

I have a function which lets the user search for a specific word like "ice-cream" which brings up all the ice-cream stores, but I want them to be able to add that store to an external page called favorites.html when they click on "add to favorites" button. The Add to favorites button is created within the function that I made.

Comment: Please post the function you currently have :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a solution which uses the browser's local storage instead of cookies and fulfill your task.

Let's say you have a table which has the values of Stores and in front of each store name, there is a button to add the store to favorites. When you search and click on that button, it will trigger a "click" event and send that store name to a function. Then, that function will check if there is the localStorage item in the browser. If it is not, it will set the item and store the "Store Name" inside it. Please refer the below code for better understanding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Store Name</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>My Ice Cream Store 1</td>
        <td><button class="addToFavBtn">Add to Favorites</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>

    $('.addToFavBtn').on('click', event => {
  var storeName = $(event.target).parents()[1].firstElementChild.innerHTML;

  var favorites = localStorage.getItem("favorites");
  if (!favorites){
    localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify({stores:[]}));
    favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"));
  }else{
    favorites = JSON.parse(favorites);
  }
  
  favorites.stores.push(storeName);

  localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));

});

    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you need to retrieve the favorite stores in the favorites.html file, you can retrieve those values by the "favorites" local storage item in the browser.

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"));
```